# How do i insert a value to a string, if i want to change that string's value later, but i want to keep the format?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I want to display the total price of ordered meals in a textbox. Now, it looks like "1800", but i would like to make it look like "1.800". The problem is, if I just try to Insert a "." into the string value, then it won't work due to the fact that the total price could change, if the user orders another meal. How can i keep that format if I know the total price could change?

```cs
private void fillTotalCostTextBox()
        {
            textBox_totalPrice.Text = "0";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_orders.Rows)
            {
                textBox_totalPrice.Text =
              (Convert.ToInt32(textBox_totalPrice.Text) +
             Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["price"].Value)).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: First of all, loop and sum your total and *then* update your TextBox using a format.  Does your grid use a DataSource?  If so, loop through that, not the grid.

Comment: And then you can use string formatting for currencies like `textBox_totalPrice.Text = totalAmount.ToString("C");`

Comment: Store numbers as numbers (double/int/whathaveyou). Only when you display/print them do you need to format them. That way you can total them, modify values etc.

Comment: Thank you both of you, this was the key. Doing the formatting **after** summing the prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8), as you can see on example bellow:

```
string s = "1800";
string s = string.Format("{0:#,0.#}", float.Parse(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this.

```
private void fillTotalCostTextBox()
{
  decimal totalPrice = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_orders.Rows)
  {
    totalPrice += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["price"].Value)).ToString();
  }
  textBox_totalPrice.Text = string.format("{0:#.00}", totalPrice);
}
```

If you want to display currency values you can use C  (string.format("C2", totalPrice)). Just make sure to check for nulls in the cell value or use TryCast.